# Adding significant superscript according to post-hoc test

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm trying to make this table using `tbl_summary()`. Is it possible to include the superscripts for post hoc test for each group? The post hoc test of interest in this case is `TukeyHSD`.
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you calculate the p-values, you just need to map the p-values to the location on the `tbl_summary()`. The rows can be identified by the variable name and the row type. For example, the first row in the table could be identified with `variable == "sptf_day" & row_type == "label"` (you can inspect the underlying data frame by printing `x$table_body`). Then you need to identify the column where the footnote will be placed. Use the `show_header_names()` function to print the underlying column names along with the label.

Once you have those two pieces of information, you can add a footnote like this.

```r
df %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = stat_1, 
    rows = variable == "sptf_day" & row_type == "label",
    footnote = "add your footnote text here" 
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Hi Dr. Sjoberge. I try your suggestion but it turned out to mark only one value instead of an entire row. I am thinking of selecting an entire row and then pass a vector including the superscripts to each element of the row, is it possible? Thank you

Comment: you can add any logic to select the cells you want to add footnotes using the columns and rows arguments. you can only place one unique footnote per call to the function. you can also export the gtsummary table to other formats (e.g. `as_gt()` or `as_flex_table()`) and use those packages footnote placement functions if this function is too restrictive.